# MySQL and PhpMyAdmin : Undefined index: Rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I've a little problem with my database based on **MySQL** with **PhpMyAdmin** for the administration.

When I create table with multiple line in same time, I always have this type of error when I go to the structure tab of my table in my PhpMyAdmin panel.
I don't how to fix it because when I create line by line it's work well.

I propose to show you my entire tab settings : 
*There are some french, because i'm french !*

```
Titre_de_l_album

Column  Type    Null    Default Links to    Comments
id (Primary)    int(11) No           
artiste varchar(20) Yes     NULL         
album   varchar(20) Yes     NULL         
annee   int(4)  Yes     NULL         
pistes  int(11) Yes     NULL         
duree   int(11) Yes     NULL         
Indexes

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  0   A   No  


Space usage:
Data    0   B
Index   0   B
Total   0   B
    Row Statistics:


Open new phpMyAdmin window
Warning in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#376
 Illegal string offset 'Data_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Notice in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#376
 Uninitialized string offset: 0

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Warning in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#381
 Illegal string offset 'Index_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Notice in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#381
 Uninitialized string offset: 0

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Warning in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#399
 Illegal string offset 'Data_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Notice in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#399
 Uninitialized string offset: 0

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Warning in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#399
 Illegal string offset 'Index_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Warning in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#403
 Illegal string offset 'Data_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Notice in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#403
 Uninitialized string offset: 0

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Warning in ./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#403
 Illegal string offset 'Index_length'

Backtrace

./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#509: PMA_getHtmlForSpaceUsageAndRowStatistics(
string '',
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
string 'left',
)
./libraries/tbl_printview.lib.php#589: PMA_getHtmlForTableStructure(
boolean true,
boolean false,
array,
array,
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
string 'Titre_de_l_album',
array,
array,
string '',
string 'left',
)
./tbl_printview.php#65: PMA_getHtmlForTablesDetail(
array,
string 'Album_TAR',
array,
array,
string 'left',
)
Automatically send report next time
```

Thank you for your help.
*PS: I see other topics about that but I was not successful to fix it because it's only with **Php***

**EDIT** : How I make this error

- Create a new Database `Album_TAR`
- Create a new table `Titre_de_l_album` with 6 colums
- Make this following configuration :

  - id , int , Primary, A_I
  - Artiste , varchar , 20
  - Album, varchar, 20
  - Annee , int, 4
  - Nombre, int
  - Duree, int
- Execute

And I've the message error I show you on my structure tab

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. What type of error?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for the answer, the type of erreur is : `Undefined index: Rows` apparently in `/libraries/structure.lib.php#1882`

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle : the last one for phpmyadmin : 4.3.8 and the libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11 for myslq

Comment: Please give a step-by-step scenario to reproduce this error message.

Comment: @MarcDelisle : Ok it's simple

- Create a new Database `Album_TAR`
- Create a new table `Titre_de_l_album` with 6 colums
- Make this following configuration :
 - id , int , Primary, A_I
 - Artiste , varchar , 20
 - Album, varchar, 20
 - Annee , int, 4
 - Nombre, int
 - Duree, int
- Execute

And I've the message error I show you on my structure tab

Comment: @Farnots I cannot reproduce your problem with your scenario, on 4.3.8. Did you try to reproduce it on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?

Comment: @Farnots when you create the table, what is the storage engine?

Comment: @MarcDelisle I just try also with demo.phpmyadmin.net and with the same code SQL I've no error on the demo but still on my local server. Really strange. I use InnoDB.

Comment: @Farnots strange indeed. Which MySQL server version and client library version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle it's the  5.5.41 for MySQL

Comment: Thanks, I'll retry to reproduce.

Comment: @Farnots Still cannot reproduce. phpMyAdmin 4.3.8, MySQL 5.5.41-0+wheezy1, PHP 5.4.36, libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was answered here: [Undefined index: Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330472/phpmyadmin-undefined-index-rows)
Use lower case table and field names

Comment: The problem is that answer is only a workaround. The actual answer is that it's a bug in phpMyAdmin, which appears to be addressed in a recent version [4.4.4.](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/changelog.php).