# I dont't know error phpmyadmin "undefined"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I will make a table, as many as 62 fields. when it will be saved there appears an error like the following:

[Go to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ9K5.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: Please provide some code sample, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try clearing your browser cache and restarting your browser. Also, have a look at a similar problem here on SO:
[PHPMyAdmin Undefined Index: Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330472/phpmyadmin-undefined-index-rows)

Comment: I have tried to empty it. the results remain the same. Then I made 10 fields gradually. And add the primary key, Auto Increment at the end after the addition of the field is complete.

Thank you for trying to help.